# How to make polyline layer always on top?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have 2 geojson of polygons in two different radiobox buttons, and in a checkbox a geojson polyline.
I need when the checkbox is checked and the polygon layer selection is changed the polyline layer still on the front. How can I fix that polyline layer always on the front with BringToFront() or other method exactly?

The project is simplified at jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/albertovich/fe0vtytb/

```
var poligon1 = new L.LayerGroup();
var poligon2 = new L.LayerGroup();
var polyline1 = new L.LayerGroup();
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [39.4699075, -0.382881],
  zoom: 13,
  layers: [poligon1]
});

var baseLayers = {
  "Poligon1": poligon1,
  "Poligon2": poligon2
};

var myStylePol1 = {
  "weight": 2,
  "opacity": 1,
  "color": "#FF00CC",
  "fillOpacity": 1
};

var myStylePol2 = {
  "weight": 2,
  "opacity": 1,
  "color": "#FFFF80",
  "fillOpacity": 1
};

var myStyle3 = {
  "weight": 2,
  "opacity": 1,
  "color": "#000"
};

L.geoJson(poli1, {
    style: myStylePol1
  }).addTo(poligon1),
  L.geoJson(poli2, {
    style: myStylePol2
  }).addTo(poligon2),
  L.geoJson(polyl3, {
    style: myStyle3
  }).addTo(polyline1);

var overlays = {
  "Polyline": polyline1
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

`map.on('baselayerchange',function(baselayer){ 
  baselayer.layer.getLayers()[0].bringToBack(); 
});`

Updated [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fe0vtytb/2/)

But typically baseLayers are tile layers (streets, satellite, terrain, etc.), not geoJson polygons, so you might want to take another approach, where all your layers are simple overlays

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well. Yes I know, but in this case I work with transparency and it looks more clean the result to see the streets. I guess it would be a form to do that with checkboxes and introduce conditions.

Comment: yes, you could build a form with radio buttons and checkboxes that toggles the layers on change. More work, but more flexibility